# combining both c# and python in order to make a windows form application in vs

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio, user-interface, web-applications

Is it possible to make a windows form application in visual studio using c# for the GUI and then use python in order to make api requests and database calls?  And if so how would one go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with various approaches, an approach in  visual studio is described at [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/657698/Python-Visual-Studio-and-Csharp-So-Sweet).

Accturally [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) is what makes it possible to embed python scripts to c# projects.

Comment: So with the IronPython does the c# execute the python scripts and draw data from that, is that how it would work?

Comment: You can run any script and use api but then u must parse the response of the script.